# Add "star-wars" to Star Wars tags that lack it

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

There are a number of *Star Wars* games that have tags, but lack a `star-wars-` prefix (or use `sw-` as an abbreviation). Now that we have a 35 character tag limit, would it be possible to add "star-wars" to those tags?

The ones I found are:

- [clone-wars-adventures](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clone-wars-adventures) → [star-wars-clone-wars-adventures](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-clone-wars-adventures)
- [galaxy-of-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galaxy-of-heroes) → [star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes)
- [tiny-death-star](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiny-death-star) → [star-wars-tiny-death-star](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-tiny-death-star)
- [force-unleashed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-unleashed) → [star-wars-the-force-unleashed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-the-force-unleashed)
- [force-unleashed-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-unleashed-2) → [star-wars-the-force-unleashed-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-the-force-unleashed-2)
- [lego-sw-force-awakens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-sw-force-awakens) → [lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens)

All of the proposed tag renames are under 35 characters. It would make sense to leave synonyms for some or all of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all now done:

- [clone-wars-adventures](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clone-wars-adventures) → [star-wars-clone-wars-adventures](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-clone-wars-adventures)
- [galaxy-of-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/galaxy-of-heroes) → [star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes)
- [tiny-death-star](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiny-death-star) → [star-wars-tiny-death-star](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-tiny-death-star)
- [force-unleashed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-unleashed) → [star-wars-the-force-unleashed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-the-force-unleashed)
- [force-unleashed-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-unleashed-2) → [star-wars-the-force-unleashed-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-the-force-unleashed-2)
- [lego-sw-force-awakens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-sw-force-awakens) → [lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens)